# Kubuntu 12.04, need a  light weight mp3 player

Tags: kubuntu, mp3

looking for a decent light weight mp3 player that has

1. a graphic equalizer built in
2. a loudness equalization feature

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try vlc its better and has all type of codec

Answer (score 1):

Audacious is a good music player.
To install it type in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install audacious
```

Some links for Audacious for further details :

- [Home Page](http://audacious-media-player.org/)
- [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Audacious)
- [Installation](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-audacious-33-in-ubuntu-1204.html)

Comment: This was the best of all the music players I have tried according to me! **lightweight + all good things = perfect**

Answer (score 0):

you can use umplayer ,open your terminal and paste line by line

```
wget http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/umplayer/UMPlayer-0.95/xUbuntu_11.04/umplayer_0.95_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i umplayer_0.95_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Qmmp` - it's in the official repos.

It's much like WinAmp, it even supports WinAmp skins.

It's written using Qt, so it fits well KDE.